# В поисках российского аналога C# библиотеки для генерации **PDF** документов

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

В поисках российского аналога **iText** # для генерации **PDF** документов, отчётов, счёт-фактур и разной документации. 
Рассмотрю любой вариант, рабочий, достаточно простого функционала текст, картинки, таблицы.

Идеально было бы найти продукт чисто российский, либо компании с дочкой в России или как минимум с отечественной техподдержкой способной решать вопросы, помогать, иногда на стороне клиента. (Желательно чтобы всё просто работало)

Comment: Вот тут перечислен перечень библиотек с кратким описанием их возможностей: http://habrahabr.ru/post/112707/

Comment: а чем вас басурмане не устраивают?

Comment: @DreamChild: судя по всему,

> с отечественной техподдержкой способной решать вопросы, помогать, иногда на стороне клиента

Comment: Бруно Лаваге конечно же доступно описал ихТекст костыль, но хочется родного, рабочего и красивого.

Comment: Эх, раньше ваш вопрос не встретил. FastReport .net прямо отвечает требованиям от и до.
Вот уж не думал, что его можно будет как "генератор PDF для C#" рекомендовать.
Российский, PDF от обычного до PDF/A, PDF/X, формы PDF, подписи, векторная графика внутри. Бонусом помимо текстао-таблиц-картинок поддержка кучи штрихкодов для всяких счетов и т.д. и вплоть до карт.
Самому на мейл квитанции за коммуналку в нём сделанные приходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать [Apitron.PDF.Kit](http://apitron.com/Product/pdf-kit) - ссылка на описание поддерживаемого функционала. Два типа создания документов - вручную, как в iText, добавлением элементов и генерация документа на базе стилей (можно сравнить с веб-вёрсткой html+css):

- текст, картинки таблицы;
- создание и модификация PDF;
- подписи;
- шифрование;
- программный поиск по документу PDF;
- формы PDF создание и заполнение;
- аннотации PDF.

Саппорт русскоговорящий. Есть филиалы в России, Казахстане и на Украине.
Можно ещё сравнивать по цене. Для гос. учреждений специальные условия.
Бесплатное использование бессрочной триальной версии.

Comment: Спасибо, скачиваю, смотрю